# Calculate virtual size of a transaction (SegWit address)

Tags: transactions, bitcoin

This tutorial: https://bitzuma.com/posts/making-sense-of-bitcoin-transaction-fees/

Provides the following formula:

```
v = (42 + 272×(number of inputs) + 128×(number of outputs))/4
```

However, calculating a transaction with 1 input and 2 outputs:

```
v = (42 + 272×(number of inputs) + 128×(number of outputs))/4
v = (42 + 272×(1) + 128×(3))/4
v = 174.5
```

Which doesn't match either of these two tools:

- https://coinb.in/#fees
- https://www.buybitcoinworldwide.com/fee-calculator/

Furthermore, the formula doesn't take into account different types of output transactions:

- P2SH
- P2WPKH
- P2PKH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heads up, there's a Bitcoin Stack Exchange: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/.

Anyways, let's try this out (in Fish shell, should be understandable even without knowledge of Fish):

```
set addr (bitcoin-cli -regtest getnewaddress "" bech32)
set inputs "[]"
set outputs "[{\"$addr\": 1}]"
set unfunded (bitcoin-cli -regtest createrawtransaction $inputs $outputs)
set funded (bitcoin-cli -regtest fundrawtransaction $unfunded '{"change_type": "bech32"}' | jq .hex --raw-output )
set signed (bitcoin-cli -regtest signrawtransactionwithwallet $funded | jq .hex --raw-output )
bitcoin-cli -regtest decoderawtransaction $signed
```

This gives me:

```
{
  "txid": "50633d5ff3de40650a9d0ac4669f408736b8fd98cd8129767650637c11680559",
  "hash": "dc0147a282b811ef23d7325aede8ededbedcc2ecf73321fa7a74eb89521fcdf0",
  "version": 2,
  "size": 245,
  "vsize": 164,
  "weight": 653,
  "locktime": 0,
  "vin": [
    {
      "txid": "f113bb1dc07dc7adccc546870d98d38ac9a0dd22a4d7861b1eeb0ccceb9597d7",
      "vout": 0,
      "scriptSig": {
        "asm": "00146e90108bb6b936e5e2fd9a108ba6e9ca458033b1",
        "hex": "1600146e90108bb6b936e5e2fd9a108ba6e9ca458033b1"
      },
      "txinwitness": [
        "304402200d3ab9fa5ee232c23a5d29d8fec445ae7f868bec8146de8cedfad1fae567a60802202174dfc11bf46ed0ef5fcf17334fa62fdf56d4320b8a0c0b60fdd93983dd5cd301",
        "03a29c4e49ab8f54ba07dff57c2cf2a214135bfffef101549b5935d00612af849d"
      ],
      "sequence": 4294967294
    }
  ],
  "vout": [
    {
      "value": 1.00000000,
      "n": 0,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "0 999e92cd7790d23740e8244e09c5397cd8debb67",
        "hex": "0014999e92cd7790d23740e8244e09c5397cd8debb67",
        "reqSigs": 1,
        "type": "witness_v0_keyhash",
        "addresses": [
          "bcrt1qnx0f9nthjrfrws8gy38qn3fe0nvdawm8vcw7lr"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "value": 48.99996720,
      "n": 1,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "0 e88b5a93dd8082f792f24079ee9537af56a8dfc5",
        "hex": "0014e88b5a93dd8082f792f24079ee9537af56a8dfc5",
        "reqSigs": 1,
        "type": "witness_v0_keyhash",
        "addresses": [
          "bcrt1qaz944y7aszp00yhjgpu7a9fh4at23h79y0z3ht"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

`vsize` here is 164, which is not much different than what the tools above gave me.

I believe the reason sizes differ from the tools you posted is that both public keys and signatures can be variable sized. In general, it is not possible to know precisely how big a transaction is going to be without signing it.